# "have met before" vs "met before"

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I have a question about verb tense.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question to explain which you think is correct and why?  Otherwise this question may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I didn't think I had met her before, until she jogged my memory. Now I think that I have met her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"had" is better here, for the reason you give.  However, because the sentence includes the word "before", it is clear in either case.